# Error in applying Butterworth lowpass filter in Scipy - advice for a good Wn parameter

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft, lowpass-filter

I am brand new to Digital Signal Processing and I would like to understand how to choose the parameter Wn (or the critical frequency) when aplying Butterworth lowpass filter with scipy.signal. To apply the butterworth lowpassfilter, the following Python/scipy source code can do it.

```
    from scipy.signal import butter
    from scipy.signal import filtfilt

    def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order):
        nyq = 0.5 * fs
        normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
        # Get the filter coefficients 
        b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
        y = filtfilt(b, a, data)
        return y
```

I would like to understand what could be a value for the *cutoff* parameter for my case. Suppose I have a 1kHZ (or 1000HZ) sampling rate in an audio file, and in this audio file I would like to filter out frequencies higher than 600HZ. IF I simply put 600 as cutoff requency (the threshold I want), the normalized cutoff would be 600/500=1.2, and the following error returns to me:

```
ValueError: Digital filter critical frequencies must be 0 < Wn < 1
```

So, it seems that the cutoff should never be higher than half of the sampling rate. Other values lower than 500 would work for the cutoff value, but I am not sure which one would be the best for my case. So, is there any rule of thumb to select a cutoff value considering my requirements of filtering values higher than 600Hz? or such a value would depend only on the data? is my 600Hz requirement feasible? is the butterworth filter the right solution for this?

Comment: If you sample at 1000 Hz, you cannot represent any frequency above 500 Hz. Those frequencies become aliased, they  must be filtered out before sampling to avoid aliasing.

Comment: This is not a question about programming. I suggest you ask it over at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for your answer, so, filtering at 499Hz would be a better idea right? what about the filter order? what would be the best for my case?

Comment: Over on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ there are lots of knowledgeable people that can answer your questions about filtering. You should filter below the Nyquist frequency *before* sampling, for example at 499 Hz. If you have a single sampled at 1000 Hz, it’s too late to filter at 499 Hz, you’ve already aliased those frequencies.